# Spark streaming with Kafka: when recovering form checkpointing all data are processed in only one micro batch

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, checkpointing

I'm running a Spark Streaming application that reads data from Kafka.
I have activated checkpointing to recover the job in case of failure.

The problem is that **if the application fails, when it restarts it tries to execute all the data from the point of failure in only one micro batch.**
This means that if a micro-batch usually receives 10.000 events from Kafka,  if it fails and it restarts after 10 minutes it will have to process one micro-batch of 100.000 events.

Now if I want the recovery with checkpointing to be successful I have to assign much more memory than what I would do normally.

Is it normal that, when restarting, Spark Streaming tries to execute all the past events from checkpointing at once or am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application finds it difficult to process all events in one micro batch after recovering it from failure, you can provide `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` configuration is spark-conf, either in spark-defaults.conf or inside your application.

i.e if you believe your system/app can handle 10K events per <s>minute</s> second safely, and your kafka topic has 2 partitions, add this line to spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition 5000
```

or add it inside your code :

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", "5000")
```

Additionally, I suggest you to set this number little bit higher and enable backpressure. This will try to stream data at a rate, which doesn't destabilizes your streaming app.

```
conf.set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled","true")
```

update: There was a mistake, The configuration is for number of seconds per seconds not per minute.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I've enabled back pressure and set conf.set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", "50000") and I have two Kafka partitions (so it should be a rate of 100.000) but when I restart the job after 10 minutes it tries to execute more than 500.000 events in one micro batch.

Comment: @nicola I did a mistake in above post, the configuration you specify is per second, not per minute... by 5000 i mean 5000 events per second per partition..... if you specify it to 50000, you are asking for a rate of 50K * 2 * 60 = 6M events per minute

Comment: You are right. Now it works. Thanks! Setting "spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition" did the trick!